# How to read specific html lines with python (bs4)

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

first I'm new to python and beautifulsoup.

I don't have access to the css, js files that are linked in the html code. Also I can't modify the html page.
I'm on linux and am using python3, if that matters.

I have the following page: https://pastebin.com/VqRRe02P
The actual html code that is being hosted is not formatted, I ran the code through an online html code formatter. Therefore the lines that I´ll state below won't be 100% right.

This is the code I'm currently using (not all functionalities implemented):

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
from operator import itemgetter

# ermöglicht schnelles Wechseln des Hosts (IP über die, das Interface lokal erreichbar ist)
a = 'http://192.168.68.128' # IP der Wärmepumpe
b = 'http://localhost' # für Entwicklungszwecke

# beziehe Daten vom Host
data = requests.get(b)

# lade Daten in BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

# Liste 'data' wird erstellt
data = []
var_name = []

# Alle Tabellen werden gesucht und in die Variable 'row' gespeichert
    for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
        row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
        var_name.append(row[0])
        if not row[1].startswith('\n') and row[2] in ['°C', 'bar']: # hier werden Filter angewendet, um nur relevante Daten zu speichern
        data.append(itemgetter(1)(row)) # die gefilterten Daten werden in die Liste 'data' gespeichert

print(var_name[2])


# die Strings von 'data' werden in den Datentyp float umgewandelt
data = list(map(float, data))

# hier werden die Unter- und Obergrenze festgelegt
 min_value = 0
max_value = 100

# Funktion überprüft, ob ein Wert die Untergrenze überschreitet
def check1():
    if data[1] < min_value:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)

    # Funktion überprüft, ob ein Wert die Obergrenze überschreitet
    def check2():
    if data[1] > max_value:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)

# Funktion überprüft, ob ein Fehler vorliegt
def check():
    if check1() + check2() is 2:
        return('Fehlercode: 2')
    if check1() + check2() is 1:
        return('Fehlercode: 1')
    else:
        return('OK')

if check() in 'Fehlercode: 2':
print('Email mit Fehlercode 2 senden')  # Platzhalter für Email Skript ausführen
if check() in 'Fehlercode: 1':
    print('Email mit Fehlercode 1 senden') # Platzhalter für Email Skript ausführen

 # Daten werden in eine CSV Datei namens 'auslesen.csv' gespeichert
with open('auslesen.csv', 'w') as auslesen:
    writer = csv.writer(auslesen)
    writer.writerow(data)
    auslesen.close()
```

/*
I need to read the data from the td elements in the following lines and save them into variables and output them into a text file like "var1, var2, var3,..".
The lines are 158, 204, 264, 339, 557, 579, 920, 937, 954, 1023, 1042, 1114, 1168.
*/

I can check now, if a element of the list data is exceeding the min or max value.
The problem is not all values are in degree(°C), some are in pressure(bar), so I also need to get a min or max value for bar. How do I do this?
And I also want to figure out which value exactly exceeded the min or max value and include its name and degree or bar( name is found in list var_name, but the index isn´t the same since some data from the list row/data gets filtered. Also trying cutting away document.write(); to only get the actual name with .text.strip() didn´t work.
The filtering is needed though, because otherwise I can´t convert the strings into floats.
For example, if we say "Aussentemperatur" (html code line 158) is 200.0 instead of 1.4, the wished output into the csv file would be:
Aussentemperatur, 200, °C
and keep the output going, if there are more values exceeding.
Since I don´t know how the brine heat pump behaves, when building the html page, I expect it to write some string. In this case I also want to output the string given:
Aussentemperatur, unknownstring, °C

Edit: I edited the code to the current state and added a new paragraph

Comment: If the lines are not necessarily accurate perhaps provide the expected values? There are a lot of errors in the html. Is this copied exactly (except for formatting) from source? And what happens in the above with your collection of td elements?

Comment: yes, this is copied exactly (except the formatting, which I mentioned). The expected values are dynamic, not static. It is a brine heat pump from the company dimplex. And you can check the values on the web-interface of it (the html code I linked). I want to read those values with python.

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have above?

Comment: it outputs all td elements, while I only want the values from the td elements in specific lines. For example the first value would be 1.4 (celsius) found in line 158, and this value changes all the time, since we want to know the exact temperature at all time

Comment: I don't think bs4 supports pseudo selectors like nth-of-type as I would use that to target the row by number. Could you use a counter in a loop to instead target the appropriate trs.

Comment: I'll try that. Will take some time.

Comment: dump the whole thing into a dataframe and slice out the values you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decide which of your rows to include based on whether or not it is a correctly formatted entry containing either a `°C` or `bar` entry. The sensor type can be extracted from the script text using a regular expression.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

with open('index.html') as f_html:
    html = f_html.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
readings = defaultdict(list)    # Hold per sensor readings in a dictionary

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Sensor', 'Value', 'Unit'])

    for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
        row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]

        if not row[1].startswith('\n') and row[2] in ['°C', 'bar']:
            sensor = re.search(r'\((.*?)\)', row[0]).group(1)   # Extract sensor name from script text
            value = float(row[1])
            unit = row[2]

            readings[sensor].append(value)
            csv_output.writerow([sensor, value, unit])

for sensor in sorted(readings):
    data = readings[sensor]
    print(f'{sensor}:\n  Min {min(data)}, Max {max(data)}, {data}')
```

The Python [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) can be used to easily write rows of data correctly formatted to file.

This would give you a CSV file summarised as follows:

```
Sensor,Value,Unit
Aussentemperatur,1.4,°C
Vorlauftemperatur,28.0,°C
Vorlauftemperatur,28.0,°C
Vorlauftemperatur,27.1,°C
Vorlauftemperatur,28.0,°C
Vorlauftemperatur,0.0,°C
Ruecklauftemperatur,27.1,°C
Ruecklauftemperatur,27.1,°C
Ruecklauftemperatur,28.0,°C
Ruecklauftemperatur,27.1,°C
Ruecklaufsolltemperatur,18.0,°C
Temperatur,0.0,°C
Kollektortemperatur,28.3,°C
MiniTempGKZwei,0.0,°C
Temperatur,16.3,°C
Temperatur,-999.9,°C
Solltemperatur,25.8,°C
MiniTempGKDrei,0.0,°C
Temperatur,35.1,°C
Temperatur,28.3,°C
Temperatur,0.0,°C
Solltemperatur,25.8,°C
Abtauendefuehler,17.6,°C
TempSpeicherReg,35.1,°C
TempSpeicherReg,28.3,°C
TempSpeicherReg,0.0,°C
RLTempKp,0.0,°C
VlTempKp,0.0,°C
Heissgastemperatur,0.0,°C
Raumtemperatur,35.1,°C
Raumtemperatur,28.3,°C
Raumtemperatur,0.0,°C
Raumtemperatur,0.0,°C
Raumtemperatur,0.0,°C
Temperatur,41.6,°C
Warmwasser,45.0,°C
Temperatur,0.0,°C
Wuelleneintritt,16.3,°C
Wuellenaustritt,17.6,°C
Niederdrucksensor,9.6,bar
Vorlauftemperatur,0.0,°C
```

A `defaultdict(list)` can be used to create lists of all the sensor readings for each sensor. This could then be used to display all the values afterwards and also show the minimum and maximum value found for each sensor. For example, the output would be:

```
Abtauendefuehler:
  Min 17.6, Max 17.6, [17.6]
Aussentemperatur:
  Min 1.4, Max 1.4, [1.4]
Heissgastemperatur:
  Min 0.0, Max 0.0, [0.0]
Kollektortemperatur:
  Min 28.3, Max 28.3, [28.3]
MiniTempGKDrei:
  Min 0.0, Max 0.0, [0.0]
MiniTempGKZwei:
  Min 0.0, Max 0.0, [0.0]
Niederdrucksensor:
  Min 9.6, Max 9.6, [9.6]
RLTempKp:
  Min 0.0, Max 0.0, [0.0]
Raumtemperatur:
  Min 0.0, Max 35.1, [35.1, 28.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Ruecklaufsolltemperatur:
  Min 18.0, Max 18.0, [18.0]
Ruecklauftemperatur:
  Min 27.1, Max 28.0, [27.1, 27.1, 28.0, 27.1]
Solltemperatur:
  Min 25.8, Max 25.8, [25.8, 25.8]
TempSpeicherReg:
  Min 0.0, Max 35.1, [35.1, 28.3, 0.0]
Temperatur:
  Min -999.9, Max 41.6, [0.0, 16.3, -999.9, 35.1, 28.3, 0.0, 41.6, 0.0]
VlTempKp:
  Min 0.0, Max 0.0, [0.0]
Vorlauftemperatur:
  Min 0.0, Max 28.0, [28.0, 28.0, 27.1, 28.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Warmwasser:
  Min 45.0, Max 45.0, [45.0]
Wuellenaustritt:
  Min 17.6, Max 17.6, [17.6]
Wuelleneintritt:
  Min 16.3, Max 16.3, [16.3]
```

Looking at this output, it would imply that you might need to filter min and max values based on per sensor values.

If you don't want to process values outside the range `0-100` then change to use the following lines:

```
        if 0 <= value <= 100:
            readings[sensor].append(value)
            csv_output.writerow([sensor, value, unit])
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how you could add the sensor type and also keep per sensor information. Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons when you are finished to select the answer as the accepted solution.